# Deserialize JSON message from Service Bus Queue Trigger to C# Object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have an Azure Function as below:

```
public class SaveProductDataToDatabase
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;

    public SaveProductDataToDatabase(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    [FunctionName("SaveProductDataToDatabase")]
    public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("product-data-dev-01", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Processed message: {myQueueItem}");
            
        // TODO : JSON Mapping will be added here once Service Bus Queue is Up and Running.
        _productRepository.Add(new Domain.Entities.Product());
    }
}
```

Here, `myQueueItem` will return a complex nested JSON string

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "origin": "xyz-data",
    "dateCreated": "2022-03-17T12:48:04.511Z"
  },
  "version": 6,
  "messageId": "a44f23aa-bab4-4eed-a235-5820d966f669",
  "sWrapper": {
    "sid": "zzavqw18",
    "identifiers": [
      {
        "alias": "si-sku",
        "value": [
          "8086300"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "itemType": "ITEM",
  "master": {
    "masterSource": "XYZ_PDS",
    "title": {
      "mainTitle": "XYZ - All Time Greats"
    },
    "description": {
      "longDescription": "XYZ - All Time Greats",
      "shortDescription": "XZY - All Time Greats"
    },
    "classification": {
      "identifier": "1pvfy"
    }
  }
}
```

In this, I want to extract `sWrapper.sid`, `sWrapper.identifiers.value`, and `classification.identifier` properties and assign it plain C# object. And that object will be passed to `_productRepository.Add(<C# object goes here>);`

How to handle this mapping? what's the best approach? Please advice.

Comment: There are a number of ways you can go about this. The most approachable way would probably be to create classes that represent the queue item JSON, deserialize that JSON, then extract the data you need from the classes into your Product class. Another possible approach would be to deserialize the item queue into a JsonElement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=net-6.0) and then create a new Product by selecting the specific nested fields from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can create a class/classes to represent the information you want from your service bus message.

```cs
public class ServiceBusMessage
{
    [JsonPropertyName("sWrapper")]
    public SWrapper SWrapper { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("classification")]
    public Classification Classification { get; set; }
}

public class SWrapper
{
    [JsonPropertyName("sid")]
    public string Sid { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("identifiers")]
    public SWrapperIdentifier[] Identifiers { get; set; }
}

public class SWrapperIdentifier
{
    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public string[] Value { get; set; }
}

public class Classification
{
    [JsonPropertyName("identifier")]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

Also, if your Azure Function is version 2.0 or higher, you can change your function signature to:

```cs
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("product-data-dev-01", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] ServiceBusMessage myQueueItem, ILogger log)
```

And the framework will handle deserialization for you (per [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#usage) docs).

You can then map this "request" object to whatever structure you want it in for usage.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple approaches.
option 1 - use class to deserialize and use class properties using Newtonsoft.Json

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CLASS>(JSON_STRING)
```

option 2
use System.Text.Json.Nodes to access directly to node

```
var jn = JsonNode.Parse(j)["sWrapper"].Dump("node");
jn["sid"].GetValue<string>().Dump("Value of SID");
```

[image]

P.S> again, there are may approaches...
then create a new class and populate class properties with values and pass object to fuction.